# Dns for dynamic IP's

Tags: networking, dynamic-dns

I want to know how to set dns name for a system which has dynamic IP. As of now we are using Leased line internet connection for our office which give us 16 static IP's, so all the system has static IP. Now we are intend to change to broadband connection there we won't have static IP's. What I want is with broadband's dynamic IP how can use dns to make my computer available in web for `RemoteDesktop`. I know it's easy to do, but I am new to networking and don't know where to search about this. can any refer me sites or materials?

I guess this link:[dyndns](http://dyn.com/dns/) would be useful for me, but I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 3):

After you have registered a name with a provider (I assume DynDNS, but there are others), you will need [in the following lists "same number" = "same theme"]:

1. something that gives IP addresses to the PC in you LAN
2. something that redirects the remote desktop connections to your PC
3. something that registers the dynamic IP to DynDNS

The router that connects the office to the internet often can do most of the work, because it should have

1. a DHCP server that distributes local IP addresses to the PC connected to the LAN
2. a firewall that filters the connections and translates the broadband IP to the one it gave to your PC (for remote desktop the port 3389/TCP has to be forwarded)
3. a DynDNS "client" that inserts/changes the dynamic broadband IP into DynDNS

If you manage the router, look in the router admin interface for labels or sections like

1. "LAN", "DHCP"
2. "NAT", "servers", "DMZ"
3. "dynamic dns"

If the router is managed by the provider, ask the connection provider (of course :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off with an application running on a server, inside your network.  If that's more trouble, you may also consider https://freedns.afraid.org/, which has free and low-cost options (wrt dyn.com).